# What's the probability of obtaining exactly 3 C's out of 10 exams?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The result of an exam consists in three possible grades: A, B and C, each with equal probabilities. 
What's the probability of obtaining exactly three C's out of 10 exams?
And what's the probability of obtaining 3 C's at most?

I used binomial distribution for the first one.
$\mathbb{P}(X=3) = \binom{10}{3}(1/3)^3(2/3)^7 \approx 0.25.$
Should I use binomial distribution on the second one as well? If so, how?

Very confused on how to do this. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula looks correct for exactly $3$.  To get the probability of at most $3$ just sum the probabilities for exactly $0$, exactly $1$, exactly $2$, and exactly $3$.

Comment: I thought about that, but I was very doubtful. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterA, no problem, glad it helped.